# Issue in setting up a Ruby On Rails project on another machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am setting up an existing ruby on rails project on another machine (Mac OS X) I have set up the source files then installed bundler, after then installed the required gems by running 'bundle install'. 
for setting up database i created database.yml the system uses postgres for database. then i imported all the data using the dump file. 
Now when i run rails server and hit localhost:3000 i get the following error

```
 PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "wp_posts" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"wp_posts"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"wp_posts"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1626ms

ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "wp_posts" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"wp_posts"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"wp_posts"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
):
    149:                            </li>
    150:                                <li>
    151:                                    <h2>Sunridge RV Blog</h2>
    152:                   <% if wp_post.present? %>
    153:                     <h3>Most Recent Post:</h3>
    154:                     <p><%=link_to wp_post.post_title, "/blog/#{wp_post.post_name}", :target => "_blank"%></p>
    155:                   <% end %>
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:82:in `wp_post'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:152:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__949835775984651851_2180765060'
```

***I have also executed 'rake db:migrate' but nothing happened.***

Comment: What about `rake db:create`?

Comment: Thnx for the fast response. Yes i have created the database and also loaded the schema. @Rich Peck

Comment: The error basically looks like you've not got the required db's set up. Have you tried `db:create` to set the dbs? `db:migrate` might be getting confused

Comment: @Rich Peck will it create a problem if i have already setup the database for the project? i mean i tried to setup the same project few days ago and then setup the database for that installation running all the required command like rake db:create, rake db:schema:load and importing data from the dump file. but there was some problem with the installation so i decided to do a fresh installation and using the same database by linking up using database.yml with the new installation. i am a very beginner for ROR.

Comment: Okay, you're a beginner - I'll help you further then. Do you have a DB set up currently? Want to go into chat about this?

Comment: Thnx @Rick i think the database is set up correctly because it shows records correctly i can see this by phppgadmin. and yes i would like to  take your help via chat.

Comment: Dammit, you don't have enough reputation to chat apparently. I think you'll likely have a mismatch with your `schema` - are you able to destroy your entire DB & reset?

Comment: Yes. currently i am doing the same. setting up a fresh database.

Comment: @Rick Peck i have set up a fresh database but still the same issue... i am out of clues now....

Answer (score 0):

In your database.yml, can verify that you have the correct adapter specified for your corresponding environment that you're attempting to run the application in? It should look similar to the following (fully qualified database.yml entry for postgres):

```
development:
    adapter: postgresql
    database: <project>_development
    host: localhost
    username: user
    password:
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000
    port: 5432
```